# Os Module Script Doing the Thing But throws error on terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

i am just writing a .py script using python to create directory and a file inside using the os module
this is just simple script which create directory if not exists and if exist it remove it
for in action i developed this script
have a look at this

```
import os

def new_directory(directory, filename):
  # Before creating a new directory, check to see if it already exists
  if os.path.isdir(directory) == False:
    os.mkdir(directory)
  
  else:
    path=os.path.join(directory,filename)
    os.remove(path)
    os.rmdir(directory)

  # Create the new file inside of the new directory
  os.chdir(directory)
  with open (filename,'w') as file:
    pass

  # Return the list of files in the new directory
  return os.listdir(directory)



print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
```

Simple Script But it does the job
for proof [directory and file created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggkwx.png)
but when i look at terminal it throws error
just like
[terminal o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEn8V.png)
in the terminal it throws error but in file explorer it does create file
i am not understanding why is this happening hope you could came with meaningful answer

Comment: Try to print the `path` and check if it is as you aspected.

Comment: @Marino Treid this thing it does return correct relative path

Comment: @Marino it not showing any error if i tried to execute is from python ishell then it works perfectly fine but when i tried to put all in a file to see this in action it throws error and even if it throwing error why directory does exist which clamied by intepreter to not exist "PythonPrograms/script.py"

Comment: If you call the function `new_directory()` two times with same arguments on the first time it will create the directory, on the second time it will delete the file and the directory so `os.chdir()` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If the directory already exists(In the else block), you're removing the directory, however not creating again. `os.chdir` is failing because of this.

You can fix this by adding `os.mkdir(directory)` to the else block.

Note that this setup has an issue: os.rmdir would not work if the directory is not empty, this could happen if you have written a different file to this directory. Even if you fix this, it might be a good idea to delete a directory.

This program works without errors when the directory doesn't exist already, that is the reason why it is working some times(once for every two attempts to be precise)

**Update:**

```
import os


def new_directory(directory, filename):
  # Before creating a new directory, check to see if it already exists
  if os.path.isdir(directory):
    path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    os.remove(path)
    os.rmdir(directory)  # Because of this, os.mkdir below is needed

  os.mkdir(directory)

  # Create the new file inside of the new directory
  os.chdir(directory)
  with open (filename,'w') as file:
    pass

  # Return the list of files in the new directory
  return os.listdir(directory)


print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
```

Comment: Still the error is not resolved? @SujanAdiga

Comment: Can you update the question with the modifications you have made?

Comment: i am not getting it could you update the answer with the  full script cause the changes you said to move like putting os,mkdir to else block does not giving me promising result and also i am not getting if the directory already exisi what is point of creating it again in else block by os.mkdir

Comment: Updated. Check now